# Multiply one column of matrix with fixed factor

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

this is probably a really trivial question, but I have not found a workable solution to it yet. There is a similar question posted here, but it did not get a workable answer, so I am grateful for any advice.

I have a simple 3x3 matrix and want to multiply the 2nd column by a fixed factor.
Example:

```
m<-matrix(rep(c(1,2,3),1*3),nrow=3)
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3
```

If I try to do `m[,2]*5`, it gives me `[1]  5 10 15`

The result I would like looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    1
[2,]    2    10   2
[3,]    3    15   3
```

It can't be that difficult, can it?

Comment: Just assign ito `m[,2] <- m[,2]*5` Or without assignment `m*c(1, 5, 1)[col(m)]`

Comment: yeah, that works. thank you!

Comment: I put this as an answer, for easier lookup in the future.

Comment: For a "without assignment" option, I'd do `t(t(m) * c(1,5,1))` instead.

Comment: @A. Webb. thanks, your option works too. The double transposing might not be intuitive, but a clever work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign it like this `m[,2] <- m[,2]*5`

Answer (score 0):

I think a more general approach than single column assignment would be a `sweep` with the vector `c(1,5,1)`:

```
 sweep(m, 2, c(1,5,1), "*")
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    1
[2,]    2   10    2
[3,]    3   15    3
```

Then you could apply a single vector to a matrix and not need to do repeated single column operations:

```
sweep(m, 2, c(2,5,10), "*")
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5   10
[2,]    4   10   20
[3,]    6   15   30
```

@akrun's solution in the comments `m*c(1, 5, 1)[col(m)]` seems to do this efficiently, but I had difficulty understanding how it works. It seems to depend on the precedence of operations and would have been easier for me to understand if it had been written: `c(1, 5, 1)[col(m)]*m`. That makes it clearer that the vector  `c(1, 5, 1)[col(m)]` is computed first rather than `m*c(2,5,10)` being extracted by `[col(m)]`.

Comment: This seems like overkill to do `t(t(m) * c(1,5,1))`, etc.

Comment: I don't know if doing two transposes seems simple to you. It doesn't seem that way to me. I'm guessing akrun's suggestion would outperform either yours or mine if it were scaled up.